Implementing Router Chains in Langchain Agents
I recently came across this comprehensive guide on using chains in Langchain, and I'm considering incorporating router chains into my Langchain agents to efficiently route inputs to different subchains and obtain responses.
I'd like to know if the router chains within a multiprompt chain are the correct approach for this purpose. Additionally, I'm curious about how to effectively integrate router concepts within agents.
Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to implement router chains within Langchain agents effectively?
Below is the code I am using to call the agent which utilizes the chain
response=zero_shot_agent(chain. run("what is 2+2"))
Response: Entering new MultiPromptChain chain...
response=zero_shot_agent(("what is 2+2")
Response: Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Defining the agent
llm = ChatGroq(temperature=0.1,
groq_api_key=GROQ_API_KEY,
model_name="mixtral-8x7b-32768",
max_tokens=20000)

wikipedia = WikipediaAPIWrapper()

wikipedia_tool = Tool(
name='wikipedia',
func= wikipedia.run,
description="Useful for when you need to look up a topic, country or person on wikipedia is the best website for fact check and any other details on any subject."
)

tools = [
Tool(
name = "Wikipidea Search",
func=wikipedia_tool.run,
description="useful for when you need answer questions from internet"
)
]

zero_shot_agent = initialize_agent(
agent="zero-shot-react-description",
tools=tools,
llm=llm,
verbose=True,
handle_parsing_errors=True,
max_iterations=10,
)
response=zero_shot_agent(chain.run("what is 2+2"))

